# Any way to disable printer steganography?

Tags: printer

Is there any way to disable [printer steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printer_steganography) for HP printers?

I would assume there is a way to do a firmware upgrade or jumper switch setting that would disable it.

Comment: You would have to create your own replacement firmware.

Comment: BTW stenography is another word for shorthand. You're talking about steganography. And, do you know that HP printers use it?

Comment: @hdhondt Is that like stegosaurusography, or is that something different?